# How parse nested Json in C# dynamicly?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, dynamic

I need a little help with json, btw I'm using http://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/.

I made a table class which is named "Workspace", which contains Columns and Rows. The class "Row" contains as a List all data in this row:

```
class Workspace
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> ColumnList;
    public List<Row> RowList;
}
class Row
{
public List<string> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

So what I get it's a json string and I have to parse it in a way that the data fills corectly in the workspace.
I have gotten this code so far:

```
     public void FillData(string jsonTxt)
    {
        var objectJson = DynamicJson.Parse(jsonTxt);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in objectJson)
        {
            if (!ColumnList.Contains(item.Key))
            {
                ColumnList.Add(item.Key);
            }
        }

        var i = 0;

        var newRowList = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in objectJson)
        {
            if (i < ColumnList.Count)
            {
                newRowList.Add(item.Value);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                AddRow(newRowList);
                newRowList = null;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(List<string> row)
    {
        var r = new Row();

        foreach (var s in row)
        {
            r.AddData(s);
        }
        RowList.Add(r);
    }
```

It works fine, except the json-string is nested. For example a simple Array:

```
{"Ingots":[{"ID":"1","Description":"asdf","Type":"Iron"},{"ID":"2","Description":"asdf2","Type":"Gold"},{"ID":"3","Description":"asdf3","Type":"Diamant"}]}
```

Has someone a Idea how I could manage this?
Thanks Patrick

Comment: Have you tried Newtonsoft? Get it from Nuget

Comment: Either JSON.Net or ServiceStack.Text would help you in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, I found these as well. But I couldn't use them in the right way on my project. If you are so polite and make an sample code, I would really appreciate this.